# swift ios change uilabel text value over and over

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two variable:

```
var textOne: String = "Some text"
var textTwo: String = "Some other text"
```

Now I want to assign those values to a UILabel so I loop through them over and over.

Eg. For 5sec `MyLabel.text = textOne`, then it becomes `MyLabel.text = textTwo` then it starts over so the text in the label changes every 5 seconds.

Right now I have setup two timers for two functions.

after 5sec this functions will run:

```
showTextOne() {
MyLabel.text = textOne
}
```

after 10 sec this function will run:

```
showTextTwo() {
  MyLabel.text = textTwo
}
```

But this will only change the label twice and I want to keep it changing between the two values as long as the current VC is displayed.

So is there any other way to keep changing the UILabel.text between two values?

Comment: Post your timer code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a variable to keep track of what the current text is, and then a 5 sec timer that toggles between the two options which can be very simply written like this in Swift 3.

```
var isTextOne = true

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) {
    myLabel.text = isTextOne ? textTwo:textOne
    isTextOne = !isTextOne
}
```

**UPDATE** For compatibility with pre iOS 10, watchOS 3, and macOS 10.12 since older versions do not have the block based timers:

```
var isTextOne = true

func toggleText() {
    myLabel.text = isTextOne ? textTwo:textOne
    isTextOne = !isTextOne
}

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(toggleText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: This is a good, clean answer. (Voted) The new closure-based Timer objects in iOS 10 are great. It's about time Apple added block/closure-based timers. They should have done that in iOS 4 when they introduced blocks.

Comment: @user2636197 iOS 10, macOS 10.12, watchOS 3. I'll edit the answer now to include the old way.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using either a timer or a synchronous dispatch queue.

You could for example use the following code to run the task every five seconds using the synchronous dispatch queue method.

```
let current = 0

func display() {
    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
        if self.current == 0 {
            MyLabel.text = "Hello world 1."
            self.current == 1
        } else if self.current == 1 {
            MyLabel.text = "Hello World 2."
            self.current == 0
        }
        self.display() // This will cause the loop.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run some method each 10 seconds is to use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer) with `repeats = true`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func update() {
    // Something cool
}
```